# How to Facebook page id using Facebook sdk3.1 for Android

Tags: android, facebook

In my Android application I need to post to logged in user's page that is owned by him.If there are multiple pages I need `id` of all pages.How can I get `id` of Page for posting.Please help me.

Comment: Have you tried `/me/accounts` end point?

Comment: No.Is this method will post to all pages.?If there is more than one page I want to show a pop up to select one of the pages

Comment: This will list out the `pages` the User is administering.

Comment: Can you show me a sample code

Comment: I have tried with the Facebook Graph api explorer and it is worked.I will try this with my android app.Thank you.

Comment: I have added it as answer, accept it if that solves your query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To retrieve the list of the pages you can query the following end point

```
/me/accounts
```

This end point along with [`manage_pages`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/login/page-permissions/) permission will give you the list of the pages the User administers and you can use the same along with the Page's `access_token` provided with each to post on the corresponding pages.

Comment: I have another doubt. Is there any apis like executeMeRequestAsync for getting page details?

Comment: I have no idea.How to use this api in android.Can you help me

Comment: I think what you are looking for is [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/3.0/Request)

Comment: Thank you so much.It is worked.One more doubt.How can I post to page using Page's accesstoken